# SOLVED Anyway to do this without creating another scanner in the method?

Tags: java

I just started learning how to write programs. I heard it is a bad habit to create multiple scanners in one file. How do I change this code so that I don't have to put a scanner inside the "adding" method?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Note1014{
    public static void main (String[]args){

    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);   
    int choice = 0;
    do{
        System.out.println("Please select from the following options:");
        System.out.println("1. Compare two values");
        System.out.println("2. Add a list of values");
        System.out.println("3. Create a shopping list");
        choice = scn.nextInt();

        if(choice == 2){
            adding(1);
        }

    }while(choice <4);  
    }

    public static void adding (int enter){
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    int price =0;
    int i = 0;
    while(i==0){
    System.out.println("enter price, press -1 when done");
    enter = scn.nextInt(); 
    price += enter;

    if(enter == -1){
        System.out.println("Your total is " + price);
        break;
    }
    }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: *"Anyway to do this without using scanner in the method?"* - I think you meant to ask if there was a way to do this without **creating** the scanner in the method.  Right?

Comment: If yes, then you could 1) pass the Scanner as a parameter, or 2) put the Scanner reference into a field and use that.

Comment: @StephenC Thank you so much! I know it sounds stupid but I am still at the very beginning of learning java, I would be most appreciated if I could get some code on how to change it.

Comment: `public class Note1014 { private static Scanner kbInput = new Scanner(System.in); /*... Class Methods ... */ }`. Now any method within the the **Note1014** class can use the declared Scanner object **kbInput**.

Comment: Don't put "Solved" into the question title. To mark a question as solved, accept the answer that solved your problem

Answer (score 1):

like this

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Note1014 {
static Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        int choice = 0;
        do {
            System.out.println("Please select from the following options:");
            System.out.println("1. Compare two values");
            System.out.println("2. Add a list of values");
            System.out.println("3. Create a shopping list");
            choice = scn.nextInt();

            if (choice == 2) {
                adding(1);
            }

        } while (choice < 4);

    }

    public static void adding(int enter) {

        int price = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while (i == 0) {
            System.out.println("enter price, press -1 when done");
            enter = scn.nextInt();
            price += enter;

            if (enter == -1) {
                System.out.println("Your total is " + price);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

also you have a small problem
it should be

```
if(enter !=-1)
price += enter;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the object outside the main method but inside the class and then use the same scn object inside the class as many times you want.

Comment: Thank you so much! But I got this error after I placed the new Scanner (System.in) outside the main method. I am not sure if I have done it right.. "Note1014.java:14: error: non-static variable scn cannot be referenced from a static context
                choice = scn.nextInt();"

Comment: Add static to the scanner object. `Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in); `